# Integrating security between ASP.Net and Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, authentication, reporting-services, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.Net website with the standard forms auth membership database, and then a Reporting Services instance with a bunch of reports on it.

How can I integrate the security between the two servers? Worst case, I could just frame in the reports with some code and pass a universal set of credentials to the Reporting server, but I lose security granularity...I could pass the current set of credentials the same way, but then I have to keep the two db's synched. There has to be a better way.

TIA,

CBB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom authentication provider to Sql Server Reporting Services to authenticate against your Forms Authentication Membership DB.

The link below even gives an example of authenticating against a Forms Authentication Database:

[Authentication in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152899.aspx)